# How to add new user to sql database

Tags: sql

good day

I am new to SQL databases. I have an existing database that one of my colleagues created, and I just want to add a new user to the DB.

How do I do it when:

```
USE [Tricom]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
           ([Name]
           ,[Surname]
           ,[Email]
           ,[Password]
           ,[Status]
           ,[DepartmentId]
           ,[Guid])
     VALUES
           (<Name, varchar(50),>
           ,<Surname, varchar(50),>
           ,<Email, varchar(100),>
           ,<Password, varchar(50),>
           ,<Status, int,>
           ,<DepartmentId, int,>
           ,<Guid, uniqueidentifier,>)
GO
```

So I inserted:

```
           ('david'
           ,'van staden'
           ,'ds@ik.io'
           ,123123
           ,0
           ,8
           ,<Guid, uniqueidentifier,>)
```

But it does not work.

What do I need to put into those fields and execute(f5) ?
Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a **language** used by many database systems but not a database product itself. Stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to insert a new `GUID`, then your `INSERT` statement will be:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users]
(
  [Name]
  ,[Surname]
  ,[Email]
  ,[Password]
  ,[Status]
  ,[DepartmentId]
  ,[Guid]
)
VALUES
(
  'david'
  ,'van staden'
  ,'ds@ik.io'
  ,123123  
  ,0
  ,8
  ,newid()
)
```

The [`newid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) will create a new uniqueidentifier value on insert.

Do not store the password as a string, you will need to apply [`HASHBYTES()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) or some sort of encryption.

Comment: thank you very much bluefeet. One more thing...I see that in the databse my password is shown as '123123' and not an encrypted 5c25c80bce74cf394db120f48676d479 type number. Why is that?

Comment: @DavidVanStaden You will have to apply some sort of encryption on the password `HASHBYTES('SHA1', 123123)` -- see this msdn article -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: @DavidVanStaden Though you say this is an existing database. If the already existing users have a hashed password you will likely need to use the same algorithm

Comment: @Martin Smith - I do not know what the current algorithm is...I just selected: dbo.Users>script table as>insert to>new query editor window...and the code above(in my question) is what I got. I filled the values and executed...Don't know where I should see what encryption is used...